# Retrieve via javascript/jquery/ajax/ReST the category tree

Tags: magento-1.6, rest-api

I was looking for a way to get the category tree via ReST API.

I looked [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html) but it doesn't seem to show how to fetch the category tree (it has an entry point which lists a product's assigned categories list, and that's not what I'm looking for).

I'm using Magento 1.6.2 (cannot update - even if it's possible, the guy before me working at this project killed a lot of kittens and considering the time I have to do this, and my newbieness, I cannot resurrect them) and I need to access ReST API (I already know how to do this in SOAP API). How can I create such custom entry point for ReST API? (It seems to not exist). I don't expect a long explanation. Links with their contexts are also accepted.

My intention is to use such API via a regular AJAX call:

```
$.get('entry/point', {data:needed, for:this, entry:point, function(categTree){
    //process (and build/display) the tree
}, 'json' /*or xml. actually don't care*/});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but you could look into how the admin site does this in `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController::categoriesJsonAction`. I know that it is not part of the api but will return a json response of the category tree.